# Flex - new line unrecognized

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I am doing a project with a Pascal subset. My code looks like:

```
NLINE       [\n]
BRACKET     ['('|')']

%%

{BRACKET} {
  std::cout << "Found BRACKET symbol " << yytext[0] << std::endl;
  return yytext[0];
}

{NLINE} {
  std::cout << "Found NEWLINE symbol " << yytext[0] << std::endl;
  yylineno++;
}

...

. { // anything is exactly before EOF
    std::cout << "Found ANYTHING " << yytext[0] << std::endl;
    yylval = NONE;
    return yytext[0];
}
```

I tried many ways to deal with that, also just \n instead of [\n] or [ \n] but without the expected results. Below is the output:

```
...
Found BRACKET symbol )
Found ANYTHING ;
Found ANYTHING  << where in code should be \n
```

I know that this is \n issue, because when I push the code without that it works like a charm!

Will appreciate every constructive answer.

Comment: The correct pattern to match `(` or `)` is `[()]`. Your pattern will match a parenthesis, an apostrophe, or a vertical bar.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what you mean by "when I push the code without that".

Comment: I mean when I cut all \n from input file. All just in one line, which is not highly comfortable. Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be the carriage return symbol. In case you will have similar issue, if this won't help, you should check other nonprintable characters.

In my case helped:

```
DELIM       [ \t\r]
```

DELIM is "eated" in my solution so no rule is applied.